Django channels websocket ws/chat endpoint not found on server
I have developed API and websocket chat using Django channels.
Currently on my local everything works fine. But in my remote server, API works, websocket does not works and returns 404 error.
here are some main codes:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1", "app.localhost","myserver-ip"]

CUSTOM_APPS = [
    "users",
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    "corsheaders",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework_simplejwt",
    "drf_yasg",
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    *THIRD_PARTY_APPS,
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "daphne",

    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    *CUSTOM_APPS,
]

routing.py:
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/chat/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi())
]

asgi.py:
import os
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from users.routing import websocket_urlpatterns
from app.middleware import JWTAuthMiddleware

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': django_asgi_app,
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        JWTAuthMiddleware(
            URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns)
        )
    ),
})

Redis is up and the issue is related to ALLOWED HOSTS I think.
